# Firestore / Algolia integration fail: API key problem

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am trying to add the Algolia search extension to a Firebase/Firestore project.
I have followed these steps:
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/algolia-firestore-algolia-search

Everything works until I try to deploy the extensions in Firebase through the terminal with the command:
`firebase deploy --only extensions`

This is the error I get:

```
i  extensions: Verifying secret params for firestore-algolia-search

Extensions deploy had errors:

- create firestore-algolia-search
Request had 1 validation errors: `params.ALGOLIA_API_KEY`: param was required but not provided.


Error: Extensions deployment failed validation. No changes have been made to the Extension instances on
```

When prompted in the terminal, I first entered the (Algolia) Search-Only API Key. I then realised this probably requires the admin API key, so I changed in to the admin API key in my project here:

\extensions\firestore-algolia-search.secret.local

I still get the error above.

My question: 1. which API key should I use (i think in the terminal it was stated that it would be needed by the emulator) and 2. where do I change it?

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: if this requires indexing (adding records) into algolia this would require admin key or a key which has that privilege. not the search only key

Comment: Algolia API Key: What is your Algolia API key? We recommend creating a new API key with "addObject", "deleteObject", "listIndexes", "deleteIndex", "editSettings", and "settings" permissions. Do not use the Admin API key. https://github.com/algolia/firestore-algolia-search

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing this through the console instead, where I saw the indications quoted by @cmgchess It worked!